# Avoiding repetitive code for timestamping and updating status

Tags: groovy, grails

This is some boilerplate I found myself writing on a new abstract class. It seems ripe for refactoring, but I'm not sure the best way to implement it more effectively. Is there a pattern for these sort of time-stamping/status-updating methods?

```
def create() {
    tsCreated = new DateTime()
    userCreated = springSecurityService.currentUser
    status = RequestStatus.OPEN
}

def accept() {
    tsAccepted = new DateTime()
    userAccepted = springSecurityService.currentUser
    status = RequestStatus.ACCEPTED
}

def send() {
    tsSent = new DateTime()
    userSent = springSecurityService.currentUser
    status = RequestStatus.SENT
}

def complete() {
    tsCompleted = new DateTime()
    userCompleted = springSecurityService.currentUser
    status = RequestStatus.COMPLETED
}

def cancel() {
    tsCanceled = new DateTime()
    userCanceled = springSecurityService.currentUser
    status = RequestStatus.CANCELED
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No idea about groovy, but it looks like a case for an `EnumMap<RequestStatus, Data>` with the map storing the (last) corresponding time and user. You need a single method

```
def action(RequestStatus status) {
    map.put(status, new Data(new DateTime(), springSecurityService.currentUser))
    this.status = status
}
```

If you really need 5 methods, you can define them trivially via `action`.

Comment: Neat! This highlights the value of understanding what the language has already available. Speaking of which, what's the `Data` type you're using there? It's hard to google due to its common name.

Comment: @CharlesWood You need to write `class Data`. In the most straightforward way: 2 fields and one all args constructor.

Comment: Ah! I think in Groovy this would be implemented with a plain old anonymous Map.  E.g., `map.put(status, [timestamp: new DateTime(), user: springSecurityService.currentUser])`.  Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesWood I guess so. As long as it stays in the class, it's OK, otherwise I'd avoid untyped data structures.

Comment: Not that I disagree with you, but dynamic typing is pretty fundamental to Groovy.